# how to delete a list's value from another list

Tags: python, list

If one of my lists contains the same value as another list and I want to delete that. How do I do that? List q contains the value of list y. It is a list but read from a file with `readlines()`. And when deleting I want to delete the whole line where x is in y.

```
if listx in listy:
    listq.remove(listx)
```

Comment: What do you mean? What does "the whole line where x is in y" mean? Do you have like a list of words and a list of lines and you want to remove the lines that contain one of the words? I suggest you post an example of the contents in those lists and clarify what output you want.

Comment: You could use a `set`

Comment: `list(set(a) - set(b))`

Answer (score 2):

Removing values from list_a if they are also in list_b

```
list_a = [a for a in list_a if a not in list_b]
```